# Using rg to search for two pattern within thousand of txt files

Tags: ag, rg

I have thousands of .txt files I want to search for two certain keywords/pattern. I use this command for one pattern:

`rg -t txt -i 'group of words'`

How can I use silversearcher searching for two pattern at the same time and giving me only those txt files with the two pattern in it?

What I mean is that I look for pattern A and B in one txt file, but not just pattern A or B.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. When you say you want `pattern A and B in one txt file, but not just pattern A or B` you don't want to match `foo` **or** `bar` but what exactly then? `foobar`? Providing it in terms of sample text like this would help me understand.